# How to get deleted appointment?

Tags: javafx, jfxtras

i use the agenda from jfxtras in my application. And i try to get the deleted appointment from the default edit popup. But it doens't work.

So how it is possible to get the deleted appointment in a string if i click on the delete button in the default edit popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a change in the appointments observable list...

Comment: I know. But i thought i can use this specific string to delete the appointment from my database. So it's possible? :)

Comment: You are responsible for populating the appointments collection. If the user removes an appointment via Agenda, it will be removed from the collection and you can observe that change. You have to make sure that the appointments you put into the collection, hold all the information you need to actually delete it from the database. Agenda is just an editor, you are in charge of the appointments.